# How to reverse "arrange" in sparklyr?

Tags: r, apache-spark, dplyr, apache-spark-sql, sparklyr

Here is my example

```
my_df <- data.frame(letters_col = sample(letters, 50, replace  = TRUE),
                    numbers_col =  rnorm(100), 
                    stringsAsFactors = FALSE)  %>% 
  copy_to(sc,., 'my_df_spark')



my_df %>% 
  arrange(letters_col, numbers_col) %>% 
  arrange(letters_col, numbers_col) %>%  
  arrange(letters_col, numbers_col) %>%  
  head
```

```
# # Source:     lazy query [?? x 2]
# # Database:   spark_connection
# # Ordered by: letters_col, numbers_col, letters_col, numbers_col, letters_col, numbers_col
# letters_col numbers_col
# <chr>             <dbl>
#   1 a                -2.29 
# 2 a                 0.107
# 3 a                 0.489
# 4 a                 1.29 
# 5 b                -0.473
# 6 b                 0.632
```

as you can see, the data frame is ordered multiple times by the same columns, 
my questions are:

1. Does it matter?
2. How to "undo" the ordering?

Answer (score 1):

In theory it shouldn't matter. Redundant arrange calls should be removed by the query optimizer:

```
my_df %>% 
  arrange(letters_col, numbers_col) %>% 
  arrange(letters_col, numbers_col) %>%  
  dbplyr::remote_query_plan()
```

```
== Physical Plan ==
*(1) Sort [letters_col#10 ASC NULLS FIRST, numbers_col#11 ASC NULLS FIRST], true, 0
+- Exchange rangepartitioning(letters_col#10 ASC NULLS FIRST, numbers_col#11 ASC NULLS FIRST, 4)
   +- InMemoryTableScan [letters_col#10, numbers_col#11]
         +- InMemoryRelation [letters_col#10, numbers_col#11], StorageLevel(disk, memory, deserialized, 1 replicas)
               +- Scan ExistingRDD[letters_col#10,numbers_col#11]
```

however it looks multiple repeated sorts are tripping the optimizer at the moment (Spark 2.4.0, you might consider opening [a JIRA ticket](https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/SPARK/issues) to address this issue):

```
my_df %>% 
  arrange(letters_col, numbers_col) %>% 
  arrange(letters_col, numbers_col) %>%  
  arrange(letters_col, numbers_col) %>% 
  dbplyr::remote_query_plan()
```

```
== Physical Plan ==
*(2) Sort [letters_col#10 ASC NULLS FIRST, numbers_col#11 ASC NULLS FIRST], true, 0
+- Exchange rangepartitioning(letters_col#10 ASC NULLS FIRST, numbers_col#11 ASC NULLS FIRST, 4)
   +- *(1) Sort [letters_col#10 ASC NULLS FIRST, numbers_col#11 ASC NULLS FIRST], true, 0
      +- Exchange rangepartitioning(letters_col#10 ASC NULLS FIRST, numbers_col#11 ASC NULLS FIRST, 4)
         +- InMemoryTableScan [letters_col#10, numbers_col#11]
               +- InMemoryRelation [letters_col#10, numbers_col#11], StorageLevel(disk, memory, deserialized, 1 replicas)
                     +- Scan ExistingRDD[letters_col#10,numbers_col#11]
```

As you see `Exchange rangepartitioning` is included twice in the execution plan.

There is no "undo" option. You have to go back to `my_df` ans start again.